# Completing Code to Print a shape using Turtle Library

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I made some codes that prints a shape which is really not flawless and perfect since I learned about "Turtle" library recently. Here's my codes:

```
from turtle import *

for i in range(8):
    forward(100)
    left(45)

f = 50
turns = [(40,40),(90, 40), (80, 40), (90, 40), (90, 50), (90, 40), (80, 40), (90, 40)]


forward(f)

for l_angle, r_angle in turns:
    left(l_angle)
    forward(f)
    right(r_angle)
    forward(f)
```

But the codes above only print a part of the shape I want to make. Also I do not know how can I find the coordinates of the central point of the shape. The image of the shape I want to make will be included.

Final Shape:
[image: Final Shape]

The shape that the code makes:
[image: The shape i currently made with codes above]

I tried many angles and even `penup` commands to reach the center but it is very hard since I am not aware that how much the turtle must go forward. Also it never lands on the center of my shape.

Answer (score 2):

A few strategies and suggestions:

1. Decompose the large problem into smaller sub-shapes. In this case, rhombi are the fundamental building block.
2. Try to find rotational symmetries you can exploit.
3. Don't use abstractions like lists right away--start with hardcoded, [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#WET), explicit, naive commands, then write functions and use lists only when you're sure you've found a pattern worth abstracting. This is known as ["AHA"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#AHA)--avoid hasty abstractions.

Taking it step by step, you might focus on the innermost repeated pattern of 8 rhombi. Start by simply drawing a single rhombus:

```py
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.forward(50)
t.left(45)
t.forward(50)
t.right(225)
t.forward(50)
t.left(45)
t.forward(50)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Now figure out the rotation to draw 8 rhombi in a circle:

```py
for _ in range(8):
    t.forward(50)
    t.left(45)
    t.forward(50)
    t.right(225)
    t.forward(50)
    t.left(45)
    t.forward(50)
    t.left(180) # prepare for the next rhombus
```

Now that the inner shape is complete, a good next step seems to be drawing the 8 square shapes at the next level outward. But if the 8 exterior rhombi are drawn, these squares will be drawn anyway and can be skipped.

Continue the procedure by drawing one edge rhombus:

```py
t.penup()
t.forward(120)
t.pendown()
t.left(90)
t.forward(50)
t.left(45)
t.forward(50)
t.right(225)
t.forward(50)
t.left(45)
t.forward(50)
```

Next, generalize this code for looping, which means repositioning the turtle back to the origin and resetting the heading:

```py
t.left(45)
t.penup()
t.backward(120)
t.pendown()
```

Finally, as before, add the loop and point the turtle in the right direction for the next shape:

```py
for _ in range(8):
    t.penup()
    t.forward(120)
    t.pendown()
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(50)
    t.left(45)
    t.forward(50)
    t.right(225)
    t.forward(50)
    t.left(45)
    t.forward(50)
    
    t.left(45)
    t.penup()
    t.backward(120)
    t.pendown()

    t.left(45)
```

Clean up and generalize by adding variables and abstracting away repeated code:

```py
import turtle


def draw_rhombus():
    t.forward(size)
    t.left(45)
    t.forward(size)
    t.left(135)
    t.forward(size)
    t.left(45)
    t.forward(size)


t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed("fastest")
t.pensize(4)
size = 100
long_size = size * 2.4

for _ in range(8):
    draw_rhombus()
    t.left(180)

for _ in range(8):
    t.penup()
    t.forward(long_size)
    t.pendown()
    t.left(90)
    draw_rhombus()
    t.left(45)
    t.penup()
    t.backward(long_size)
    t.pendown()
    t.left(45)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

A related question is [Creating mosaic tile grid with turtle (intro level programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77380357/creating-mosaic-tile-grid-with-turtle-intro-level-programming/77381510#77381510), which involves a similar pattern except hexagonal instead of octagonal, and with the shape drawn repeatedly in a grid.

---

As a turtle-specific side-note, avoid `from turtle import *` as this floods the global namespace with over 120 functions, leading to bugs and name clashes. I also always create a turtle instance to avoid confusion and bugs caused by the functional interface.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate @ggorlen's breakdown and solution to this problem (+1).  Using his rules #1, #2, and #3, I'd break the problem down to the sub-shape:

[image]

and its mirror reflection.  That reduces our drawing of the shape to:

```
import turtle

for heading in range(0, 360, 360//8):
    turtle.setheading(heading)

    for direction in range(-1, 2, 2):
        for angle in (0, 45, -90, 135):
            turtle.right(direction * angle)
            turtle.forward(50)

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(0, 0)
        turtle.pendown()

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK ... There is a nice answer by *ggorlen* from which one you can learn the right strategy of approaching coding tasks and there is a nice answer by *cdlane* which simplifies the code by another choice of the building block pattern for repeated draw.

*The reason why I had decided to add another answer is twofold*:

**The main reason** is the fact, that the other answers don't answer *your actual question about placing the origin of the figure in the center of the screen*

> "I do not know how can I find the coordinates of the central point of the shape".

See the voluminous comments in the code below for how it could be done and for some other hints towards better code (your original code does not draw the right figure):

```
# from turtle import * # pollutes the code with a huge amount of variable names (symbols)
from turtle import forward, left, right, penup, goto, pendown, done
#           ^-- is much better and in harmony with Zen of Python 
#           https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python 
#           (" Explicit is better than implicit." ) 
f = 50

# The initial Turtle x0,y0 position is (0,0) in a coordinate system with its origin at the center
# of the Turtle graphics window. In order to have the center of the figure at the center of 
# the window it is necessary to start drawing at the position of left end of lower horizontal
# line of the figure which can be calculated for the given figure as follows:
from math import tan, pi
penup();goto( -1*f, -1*f/tan((360/16)*pi/180));pendown()
# ^-- calculates the distance from the center of the figure to the left end of lower horizontal side
#   from a right triangle where the given side has length f and the angle is 45/2 == 22.5 == 360/16

for i in range(8):
    forward(2*f)
    left(45)

forward(f)

# turns = [(40,40),(90, 40), (80, 40), (90, 40), (90, 50), (90, 40), (80, 40), (90, 40)]
#           ^-- the choice of angles is not correct and leads to a wrong figure

""" (see explanation of the "switch" in the second part of the answer)
turns = [(45,45),(90, 45), (90, 45), (90, 45), (90, 45), (90, 45), (90, 45), (90, 45)]

for l_angle, r_angle in turns:
    left(l_angle)
    forward(f)
    right(r_angle)
    forward(f)
"""
# instead of using a list and looping over repeating agle pairs you can simplify the code
# as follows: 
right(45)
for _ in range(8):
    left(90); forward(f);    right(45); forward(f)
#"""    

penup();goto(0,0) # place the Turtle at the origin of the coordinate system

done()
```

---

**The other reason** is that by utilizing another choice of the basic drawing pattern block as it was done in the other answers:

[image: drawing pattern along with final result]

it is possible to reduce the required code to one very simple loop only:

```
import turtle
anglesOfTurn = 8*[45, -90, 135, 45, 135, -90, 45, 90]
for angle in anglesOfTurn:
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(angle)
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

---

Interesting variant of this kind of approach is to refrain from usage of Python list multiplication and specification of number of loop runs making the code longer, but maybe easier to follow/understand by a beginner:

```
import turtle
""" Put a '#' in front of THIS line to switch to running the code block below: 
#   Remove the leading '#' in the line above to run the other code block:
anglesOfTurn = 8*[45, -90, 135, 45, 135, -90, 45, 90]
for angle in anglesOfTurn:
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(angle)
"""
while True:
    turtle.forward(50); turtle.right(    45 )
    turtle.forward(50); turtle.left(     90 )
    turtle.forward(50); turtle.right(   135 )
    turtle.forward(50); turtle.right(    45 )
    turtle.forward(50); turtle.right(   135 )
    turtle.forward(50); turtle.left(     90 )
    turtle.forward(50); turtle.right(    45 )
    turtle.forward(50); turtle.right(    90 )
    if turtle.heading() == 0: break # back at start, so stop here 
#"""
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

You can easily switch between the two code variants by adding or removing `#` in front of the first line explaining the "switch" to see that both variants are equivalent and draw the same figure.

**Notice** that the code above does not need any initial repositioning of the Turtle because the drawing starts from the initial Turtle position at the center of the graphics.

Answer (score -1):

this is my answer:

```
from turtle import *
for j in range (0,360,45):
    speed(100)
    left(j)
for i in range (2):
    forward(100)
    left(45)
for i in range (4):
    forward(100)
    left(90)
left(90)
forward(100)
home()
exitonclick()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'for' statement on line 2`. After fixing that, this doesn't produce the expected result, there's no explanation, and it promotes poor coding practices like `from turtle import *` which pollutes the global namespace.