# Creating mosaic tile grid with turtle (intro level programming)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

below is the assignment for my intro level programming class

For this assignment, you will create your own intricate mosaic tile pattern using turtle graphics.  Your mosaic must meet the following requirements:

1. must make use of the loop programming construct
2. 16 tiles of the same pattern
3. 3 or more different colors

Im trying to keep this super simple because I'm very much a beginner. Here is my code so far, and I'm getting stuck on using a for loop to have a turtle draw a pattern, move to the right across the screen and draw that pattern again 4 separate times using a for loop. I'm testing this on one turtle and it moves the first time, but then draws the pattern in the same spot the other 3 times.

```
# Creating a mosaic using greg the turlte from the Turtle Graphics module

import turtle 

#setting up the screen environment 
myscreen = turtle.Screen()
myscreen.bgcolor("black")
myscreen.screensize(400, 400)

# Initializing turtles, their writing speed, and pen color
greg = turtle.Turtle()
greg.speed(0.5)
greg.color('red')

# Set starting locations for each turtle
greg.up()
greg.goto(-250, 250)
greg.down()

#create loop function for each turtle 
y = -250
angle = 91
for y in range(4):
    for x in range(50):
        greg.forward(x)
        greg.left(angle)
    greg.up()
    greg.goto(y, 250)
    greg.down()
    y = y + 100

myscreen.exitonclick()
```

image of the output
[image: image of the output]

What my output should look like in structure
[image: What my output should look like in structure]

I've tried rearranging the for loops but I think the logic of for statements hasn't quite clicked in my brain yet.

Comment: You've used the same variable name for two purposes.  Your `for` loop is going to set `y` to 0, 1, 2 and 3.  Adding 100 at the end of the loop does nothing, because it will be immediately reassigned to the next loop value.  Since you don't really need that counter, I suggest you use `for _ in range(4):`.  That should do what you want.

Comment: Also, you should do the "up/goto/down" sequence in your loop BEFORE you do the drawing.  Make sure you're in the right place for each setup.

Comment: Looks similar to [this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77032652/completing-code-to-print-a-shape-using-turtle-library/77046540#77046540) except with 6 branches rather than 8. Break the problem down into small bits. For example: can you draw a rhombus? Once you've done that, can you arrange 12 rhombuses into the shape? Once you've done that, can you write a loop to draw 16 of them in a grid? Following [this other approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77061906/6243352) you can draw a line from the center to the edge and rotate it around a circle to make the shape.

Comment: After reading the comment by *ggorlen* I couldn't resist to add another answer to the mentioned approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77381211/7711283 in order to emphasize that the right choice of the building block is vital for code simplicity and brevity.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most critical skills in programming is decomposing problems into smaller chunks until they're solvable, then recomposing the small solutions to solve large problems. Trying to do too much at once will lead to a confused state, like a ball of yarn with no obvious entry point for untangling it.

Applying that technique here, this problem can be decomposed into many smaller sub-problems, the simplest of which is drawing a rhombus, which is the shape the tiling is composed of:

```py
import turtle 

size = 80
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.forward(size)
t.left(60)
t.forward(size)
t.left(120)
t.forward(size)
t.left(60)
t.forward(size)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

At each sub-step, some trial and error will be necessary to get things right, but at least the goal will be simple enough that it's achievable. Run the code frequently to get feedback about each change.

This rhombus can be rotated around the circle to draw the inner portion of the shape, making a turn to prepare the turtle for the next shape:

```py
# ...

for _ in range(6):
    t.forward(size)
    t.left(60)
    t.forward(size)
    t.left(120)
    t.forward(size)
    t.left(60)
    t.forward(size)

    # prepare to draw the next shape
    t.left(60)

# ...
```

Repeat the process for the outer shape. First, draw one rhombus:

```py
# ...

# move to the outside
t.penup()
t.forward(size)
t.left(60)
t.forward(size)
t.pendown()

# draw the first outer rhombus
t.right(120)
t.forward(size)
t.right(60)
t.forward(size)

# ...
```

With this code to draw one outer rhombus, add a loop and a preparatory turn to draw 6 outer rhombi:

```py
# move to the outside
t.penup()
t.forward(size)
t.left(60)
t.forward(size)
t.pendown()

for _ in range(6):
    t.right(120)
    t.forward(size)
    t.right(60)
    t.forward(size)

    # prepare to draw the next shape
    t.left(120)
```

With the main pattern completed, the code can be abstracted into a function called `draw_tiled_hexagon` and used 16 times in a grid pattern using nested loops (or with relative movement commands line `forward()`/`left()`, which are a bit more in the spirit of turtle):

```py
import turtle

def draw_tiled_hexagon(t):
   # add all the drawing code so far
   ...

# ...

size = 60
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed("fastest")

for y in range(-2, 2):
    for x in range(-2, 2):
        t.penup()
        t.goto(
            x * size * 4 + size * 2,
            y * size * 3.47 + size * 2 # 3.47 is kinda hacky
        )
        t.pendown()
        draw_tiled_hexagon(t)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Lastly, add color. Doing so was a bit tricky, since filling only works when the path completely closes the shape. I had to adjust my earlier code to account for that, which is normal during the course of development.

```py
import turtle 
from random import random


def random_color():
    return random(), random(), random()


def draw_tiled_hexagon(t):
    for _ in range(6):
        t.begin_fill()
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(60)
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(120)
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(60)
        t.forward(size)
        t.end_fill()

        # prepare to draw the next shape
        t.left(60)

    # move to the outside
    t.penup()
    t.forward(size)
    t.left(60)
    t.pendown()

    for _ in range(6):
        t.begin_fill()
        t.forward(size)
        t.right(120)
        t.forward(size)
        t.right(60)
        t.forward(size)
        t.right(120)
        t.forward(size)
        t.end_fill()

        # prepare to draw the next shape
        t.penup()
        t.forward(size)
        t.pendown()


turtle.bgcolor("black")
size = 60
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed("fastest")
t.color("blue")
t.pensize(4)

for y in range(-2, 2):
    for x in range(-2, 2):
        t.penup()
        t.goto(
            x * size * 4 + size * 2,
            y * size * 3.47 + size * 2 # 3.47 is kinda hacky
        )
        t.pendown()
        t.fillcolor(random_color())
        draw_tiled_hexagon(t)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

This is not the most elegant solution, but it works, and I was able to apply a methodical problem solving strategy to get there. After achieving correctness, there are usually opportunities to optimize and simplify, left as an exercise here.

See also [Completing Code to Print a shape using Turtle Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77032652/completing-code-to-print-a-shape-using-turtle-library/77046540#77046540), which is a very similar pattern. I solved that problem with the same basic strategy as this.

Answer (score 0):

**See the comments to your question by *Tim Roberts* for explanation why your code does not run as expected.** They describe it in detail, so I won't repeat them here adding only some general hints towards good programming style and inspiration for own coding in the special context of the asked question:

---

It is a good idea to choose naming of variables in a way explaining what they are for. This helps to see if the code does what it should and provides as a side-effect also already some code documentation and helps with debugging if the code fails to deliver the intended result.

Below a suggestion how can it be done (including clarification what `myscreen.screensize()` actual does) :

```
# Creating a mosaic using `greg` the Turtle from the Turtle Graphics module
import turtle 

#setting up the screen environment 
myscreen = turtle.Screen() 
#                 ^-- Screen isn't a turtle class, but a function (see NOTICE:)
#                 print(f"{myscreen=},  {turtle._Screen=}") 
#                 myscreen=<turtle._Screen object at 0x7f140688fd30>,  turtle._Screen=<class 'turtle._Screen'>

# NOTICE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77390810/7711283
"""Preamble: 
    turtle is a mess and not nearly as beginner-friendly as it could be. 
There are a ton of inconsistencies in the API and it breaks almost every rule 
of the Zen of Python. It's probably the way it is because it was written a long 
time ago and hasn't been changed much since. """
myscreen.screensize(400, 400)
#       ^-- sets the maximal size of canvas to show using scrolling in case of too small window 
myscreen.setup(960, 810) 
#       ^-- sets the actual initial screen size of the Turtle canvas/screen/window
#       ^-- (960x810 are the default values on my system)

myscreen.bgcolor("black")
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'] # list of three colors to loop over

# Initializing turtles, their writing speed
greg = turtle.Turtle()
greg.speed(0.5)

# Set reference location and heading of turtle drawing the first tile
x0, y0, direction = -250, 250, 0 # reference x, y position and the reference turtle heading angle

# Initialize values required to draw the tile: 
turnAngle = 91
distanceXbetweenTiles, distanceYbetweenTiles = 40, 40

# create tiles in a loop over tile numbers: 
for tileNo in range(4): # tileNo will start with zero 0 and run up to 3
    #               ^-- draw four tiles: 
    greg.up()
    # move and turn the turtle so that it will draw the next tile 
    greg.goto(x0 + tileNo*distanceXbetweenTiles, y0 - tileNo*distanceYbetweenTiles)
    greg.setheading(direction) # make sure the turtle has always same orientation (i.e. heading angle)
    greg.color(colors[tileNo%3]) # loop over color indices: 0,1,2, 0,1,2, 0,1,2, ...
    greg.down()
    # draw one tile at the above chosen position: 
    for distance in range(50):
        greg.forward(distance)
        greg.left(turnAngle)
 
myscreen.exitonclick()
```

[image: four tile pattern drawn by greg the Turtle]

---

Changing in the code above two lines as follows:

```
for tileNo in range(16):
    #               ^-- draw sixteen tiles: 
    greg.up()
    # move and turn the turtle so that it will draw the next tile 
    greg.goto(x0 + (tileNo%4)*distanceXbetweenTiles, y0 - (tileNo//4)*distanceYbetweenTiles)
```

will create a nice looking pattern:

[image: nice looking tile pattern]

The changed code uses both the modulo operator `%` and the integer division `//` in order to derive the appropriate tile position from the `tileNo` in the loop numbering the tiles starting with `0` up to `15`.

If you want a nice image of the pattern without the arrow representing the Turtle add the line:

```
greg.hideturtle()
```

to get:

[image: tile pattern without Turtle arrow obtained using greg.hideturtle()]

---

With a `turnAngle = 92` and

```
    for distance in range(34):
        greg.forward(distance)
        greg.left(turnAngle)
    greg.forward(distance)
    greg.left(90)
    greg.forward(distance-4)
```

you get:

[image: more tile-like pattern]

The added lines finalize the line pattern of the tile to a nicer looking one by drawing the last line at angle of 90 with reduced distance compared to the line drawn before.

**Interesting side-effect of coloring with red, green and blue on a black background and the arrangement of colors in the grid is here that the pattern gets 3D-depth. The red tiles appear in the foreground, the blue ones stay in background and the green ones are somewhere in between. It is a known color related optical illusion effect amplified here by the choice of the special tile pattern.**

---

Considering the comments on how to draw the second tile pattern mentioned in the question here the appropriate code which uses the approach from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77381211/7711283) to another, similar question to obtain the tile pattern:

```
# Creating a mosaic using greg the Turtle from the Turtle Graphics module
import turtle
#setting up the screen environment 
myscreen = turtle.Screen()
myscreen.bgcolor("black")

# Initializing the turtle and its drawing speed
greg = turtle.Turtle()
greg.speed(0.5)

# Set reference location and heading of turtle drawing the first tile
x0, y0, direction = -300, 260, 0 # reference x, y position and the reference turtle heading angle

# Initialize values required to draw the tile: 
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'] # list of three colors to loop over
anglesOfTurn = 6*[-60, 120, 60, 120, -60, 120]
distance = 50
distanceXbetweenTiles, distanceYbetweenTiles = 200, 200*0.75**0.5

# Draw tiles in a loop over tile numbers: 
for tileNo in range(16): # tileNo will start with zero 0 and run up to 15
    #               ^-- draw sixteen tiles: 
    greg.up()
    # move and turn the turtle so that it will draw the next tile 
    greg.goto(x0 + (tileNo%4)*distanceXbetweenTiles, y0 - (tileNo//4)*distanceYbetweenTiles)
    greg.setheading(direction) # make sure the turtle has always same orientation (i.e. heading angle)
    greg.color(colors[tileNo%3]) # loop over color indices: 0,1,2, 0,1,2, 0,1,2, ...
    greg.down()
    # draw one tile at the above chosen position: 
    greg.begin_fill()
    for angle in anglesOfTurn:
        greg.forward(distance)
        greg.right(angle)
    greg.end_fill()

greg.hideturtle()
myscreen.exitonclick()
```

[image: hexagon tile pattern]

By the way: I like the previous tile pattern much more as it looks more appealing to my aesthetics than the hexagon tiles one.

This one below is much more interesting, istn't it?

[image]

Here the code which created the above result:

```
import turtle
#setting up the screen environment 
myscreen = turtle.Screen()
myscreen.bgcolor("black")

# Initializing the turtle and its drawing speed
greg = turtle.Turtle()
greg.speed(0.5)
greg.pensize(3)

# Set reference location and heading of turtle drawing the first tile
x0, y0, direction = -150, 260, 0 # reference x, y position and the reference turtle heading angle

# Initialize values required to draw the tile: 
colors = ['red', 'white','green', 'blue','yellow','pink'] # list of colors to loop over
anglesOfTurn                = 6*[-60, 120, 60, 120, -60, 120]
anglesOfTurnInnerRhombs     = 6*[-60, -120, -60, -60]
distance = 30
#distanceXbetweenTiles, distanceYbetweenTiles = 200, 200*0.75**0.5
distanceXbetweenTiles, distanceYbetweenTiles = 3*distance, 2*distance*0.75**0.5
# create tiles in a loop over tile numbers: 
for tileNo in range(16): # tileNo will start with zero 0 and run up to 15
    #               ^-- draw sixteen tiles: 
    greg.up()
    # move and turn the turtle so that it will draw the next tile 
    greg.goto(x0 + (tileNo%4)*distanceXbetweenTiles, y0 - (2*(tileNo//4)+tileNo%4)*distanceYbetweenTiles)
    greg.setheading(direction) # make sure the turtle has always same orientation (i.e. heading angle)
    greg.color( colors[(tileNo+1)%6]) # loop over color indices: 0,1,2, 0,1,2, 0,1,2, ...
    greg.fillcolor( colors[(tileNo+2)%6])
    greg.down()
    # draw one tile at the above chosen position: 
    greg.begin_fill()
    for angle in anglesOfTurn:
        greg.forward(distance)
        greg.right(angle)
    greg.end_fill()
    greg.right(30)
    greg.color( colors[(tileNo+3)%6])
    greg.fillcolor( colors[(tileNo+4)%6])
    greg.begin_fill()
    for angle in anglesOfTurnInnerRhombs:
        greg.forward(distance)
        greg.right(angle)
    greg.end_fill()
    greg.penup()
    greg.goto( x0+(tileNo%4)*distanceXbetweenTiles+2*distance,  y0-(2*(tileNo//4)+tileNo%4)*distanceYbetweenTiles )
    greg.setheading(120)
    greg.color("gray")
    greg.pendown()
    for _ in range(6):
        greg.forward(2*distance)
        greg.left(60)
    
greg.hideturtle()
myscreen.exitonclick()
```

Playing a bit more around with the code and speeding up the rendering using `tracer()` results in fast rendering of impressive patterns like for example this one:

[image: full space tile pattern with different colors]

Here the code generalized a bit to allow defining any list of colors and the size of the tile surface which width in tiles decides about the distribution of tiles with same color:

```
# Creating a mosaic using greg the Turtle from the Turtle Graphics module
import turtle
#setting up the screen environment 
myscreen = turtle.Screen()
myscreen.bgcolor("black")

# Initializing the turtle and its drawing speed
greg = turtle.Turtle()
greg.speed(0)
greg.pensize(3)
# Set reference location and heading of turtle drawing the first tile
distance = 21
widthNoOfTiles=17
heightNoOfTiles=18
myscreen.tracer(widthNoOfTiles)

x0, y0, direction = -1*int( (1.5*widthNoOfTiles-1)*distance), int( (heightNoOfTiles+0.5*widthNoOfTiles-1)*2*distance*0.75**0.5), 0 
#   ^-- reference x, y position and the reference turtle heading angle

# Initialize values required to draw the tile: 
colors = ['red', 'white','green', 'blue','yellow','pink','black'] # list of colors to loop over
anglesOfTurn                = 6*[-60, 120, 60, 120, -60, 120]
anglesOfTurnInnerRhombs     = 6*[-60, -120, -60, -60]
#distanceXbetweenTiles, distanceYbetweenTiles = 200, 200*0.75**0.5
distanceXbetweenTiles, distanceYbetweenTiles = 3*distance, 2*distance*0.75**0.5

# create tiles in a loop over tile numbers: 
for tileNo in range(widthNoOfTiles*heightNoOfTiles): # tileNo will start with zero 0 and run up to 15
    #                           ^-- draw all the tiles: 
    greg.up()
    # move and turn the turtle so that it will draw the next tile 
    greg.goto(x0 + (tileNo%widthNoOfTiles)*distanceXbetweenTiles, y0 - (2*(tileNo//widthNoOfTiles)+tileNo%widthNoOfTiles)*distanceYbetweenTiles)
    greg.setheading(direction) # make sure the turtle has always same orientation (i.e. heading angle)
    greg.color( colors[(tileNo+1)%len(colors)]) # loop over color indices: 0,1,2, 0,1,2, 0,1,2, ...
    greg.fillcolor( colors[(tileNo+2)%len(colors)])
    greg.down()
    # draw one tile at the above chosen position: 
    greg.begin_fill()
    for angle in anglesOfTurn:
        greg.forward(distance)
        greg.right(angle)
    greg.end_fill()
    greg.right(30)
    greg.color( colors[(tileNo+3)%len(colors)])
    greg.fillcolor( colors[(tileNo+4)%len(colors)])
    greg.begin_fill()
    for angle in anglesOfTurnInnerRhombs:
        greg.forward(distance)
        greg.right(angle)
    greg.end_fill()
    greg.penup()
    greg.goto( x0+(tileNo%widthNoOfTiles)*distanceXbetweenTiles+2*distance,  y0-(2*(tileNo//widthNoOfTiles)+tileNo%widthNoOfTiles)*distanceYbetweenTiles )
    greg.setheading(120)
    greg.color("gray")
    greg.pendown()
    for _ in range(6):
        greg.forward(2*distance)
        greg.left(60)
    
greg.hideturtle()
myscreen.exitonclick()
```

The code above allows definition of any number of colors as for example:

```
colors = [
    'burlywood', 'white','green yellow', 'aquamarine','violet red','yellow','pink','moccasin','azure','cyan',
    'coral','light blue','maroon','orchid','sienna','seashell','violet','turquoise','yellow green','tomato',
    'thistle','tan','salmon'
] # list of colors to loop over
```

generating then tile patterns like:

[image: tile pattern with a palette of 23 colors]