# Turtle Library Python: What am I doing when I do screen = Screen() if Screen isn't a class?

Tags: python, oop, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am following along Dr. Angela Yu's "100 days of code" course on Udemy for Python. I'm on day 22 using Turtle to recreate the Pong game.

I thought Screen() was a class because I've been treating it exactly like Turtle() and coding like this:

```
 from turtle import Turtle, Screen

 tort = Turtle()

 display = Screen()
 display.bgcolor("orange")
 display.exitonclick()
```

But whenever I start typing out Screen() in pycharm community, in the dropdown that pops up, "Screen()" has a little red circled "f" next to it. In contrast, when I begin typing "Turtle() or "Turtle" it has a little blue circled "c" next to it.

[circled red f symbol next to Screen in popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BueqL.png)
[circled red f symbol next to Screen in popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAGzl.png)

Does this mean Screen() definitely isn't a class? If so, why can I use Screen() to create an object just like I can with Turtle()?

It's not that my code isn't working, I just don't understand WHY it works that way.

Plus, I've also realized I can accomplish the same thing by writing my code this way:

```
 from turtle import Turtle

 tort = Turtle()

 tort.screen.bgcolor("orange")
 tort.screen.exitonclick()
```

BUT pycharm yellow underlines the "exitonclick()" part with the statement "Unresolved attribute reference 'exitonclick' for class 'TurtleScreen' " which only confuses me more because....then why does it work just fine when I run it.

Answer (score 4):

Preamble: turtle is a mess and not nearly as beginner-friendly as it could be. There are a ton of inconsistencies in the API and it breaks almost every rule of the [Zen of Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python). It's probably the way it is because it was written a long time ago and hasn't been changed much since. So don't be too surprised when parts of the turtle API or internals are *inexplicably weird* or inconsistent or an IDE autocomplete gets confused.

---

Looking at the source code for CPython in `turtle.py`:

```py
def Screen():
    """Return the singleton screen object.
    If none exists at the moment, create a new one and return it,
    else return the existing one."""
    if Turtle._screen is None:
        Turtle._screen = _Screen()
    return Turtle._screen
```

[`Screen()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c829975428253568d47ebfc3104fa7386b5e0b58/Lib/turtle.py#L3694) is a function, just named in a way that breaks with the PEP-8 Python style guide which specifies that [functions should be `lower_snake_case`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) and [classes should be `UpperPascalCase`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names). The rationale for the divergence is probably that it's a singleton instance, so it returns the existing `_Screen` or creates a new one if none exists.

On the other hand, [`Turtle`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c829975428253568d47ebfc3104fa7386b5e0b58/Lib/turtle.py#L3829C1-L3839C23) is clearly a class:

```py
class Turtle(RawTurtle):
    """RawTurtle auto-creating (scrolled) canvas.

    When a Turtle object is created or a function derived from some
    Turtle method is called a TurtleScreen object is automatically created.
    """
    _pen = None
    _screen = None

    def __init__(self,
                 shape=_CFG["shape"],
                 undobuffersize=_CFG["undobuffersize"],
                 visible=_CFG["visible"]):
        if Turtle._screen is None:
            Turtle._screen = Screen()
        RawTurtle.__init__(self, Turtle._screen,
                           shape=shape,
                           undobuffersize=undobuffersize,
                           visible=visible)
    # ...
```

---

As for your second question, there's a comment in the [`exitonclick` docstring](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c829975428253568d47ebfc3104fa7386b5e0b58/Lib/turtle.py#L3812C9-L3813C32):

> This is a method of the `Screen`-class and not available for `TurtleScreen` instances.

The reason for the comment is that `exitonclick` is a method inside the `_Screen` class which inherits from `TurtleScreen`. When you create a `Turtle()` and don't specify a screen, the `def Screen` function shown above is called, creating a `_Screen` instance. The comment appears slightly incorrect, and seems like it should refer to the `_Screen` class.

So the `exitonclick` method will be available to your instance at runtime, but the path to get there has conditions that the IDE may not be able to resolve statically, like:

```py
class RawTurtle(TPen, TNavigator):
    """Animation part of the RawTurtle.
    Puts RawTurtle upon a TurtleScreen and provides tools for
    its animation.
    """
    screens = []

    def __init__(self, canvas=None,
                 shape=_CFG["shape"],
                 undobuffersize=_CFG["undobuffersize"],
                 visible=_CFG["visible"]):
        if isinstance(canvas, _Screen): # this branch will be taken in OP's case
            self.screen = canvas
        elif isinstance(canvas, TurtleScreen):
            if canvas not in RawTurtle.screens:
                RawTurtle.screens.append(canvas)
            self.screen = canvas
        elif isinstance(canvas, (ScrolledCanvas, Canvas)):
            for screen in RawTurtle.screens:
                if screen.cv == canvas:
                    self.screen = screen
                    break
            else:
                self.screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
                RawTurtle.screens.append(self.screen)
        else:
            raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad canvas argument %s" % canvas)
```

Based on the above code, the static analyzer appears to be using the parent class `TurtleScreen` as the type of `Turtle().screen`, failing to detect that OP's code will take the branch that sets the `_Screen` subclass that has the `exitonclick` method.

Turtle also uses [metaprogramming to set up classes at runtime](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c829975428253568d47ebfc3104fa7386b5e0b58/Lib/turtle.py#L4007C1-L4008C68):

```py
def _make_global_funcs(functions, cls, obj, init, docrevise):
    for methodname in functions:
        method = getattr(cls, methodname)
        pl1, pl2 = getmethparlist(method)
        if pl1 == "":
            print(">>>>>>", pl1, pl2)
            continue
        defstr = __func_body.format(obj=obj, init=init, name=methodname,
                                    paramslist=pl1, argslist=pl2)
        exec(defstr, globals())
        globals()[methodname].__doc__ = docrevise(method.__doc__)

_make_global_funcs(_tg_screen_functions, _Screen,
                   'Turtle._screen', 'Screen()', _screen_docrevise)
```

This populates the methods of the `_Screen` class onto the module dynamically. I don't think this is a factor in this particular case, since you're not using the functional (global) singleton interface, but practices like this are liable to confuse static analyzers used by IDEs.

I wouldn't worry too much about these sort of false positives. If this bothers you, you might try using an alias to reach the screen, like `tort.Screen().exitonclick()`. I haven't tested this in PyCharm though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! It does put me at ease about the inconsistencies. I definitely don’t completely understand everything after the preamble yet but I’m excited to break it down more as I get further in my course.

Comment: No problem. If you're just starting out, all of these internals are probably too complex to understand, so you can mostly ignore it as long as your code works. Curiosity is good though. The problem with turtle is that it's a [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction). It's supposed to make graphics easy, so you don't have to worry about the library's internals or tkinter, but realistically it raises confusing errors revealing its design or tkinter all the time. If it were "tighter", it'd present a less leaky interface without internal errors and a consistent design.